# Who and where is Artie’s mother in Shrek?

Tags: shrek, shrek-the-third

In Shrek the Third, Shrek and Artie talk about their respective fathers.

But no mention was given to Artie’s mother.

Comment: I've reached out to the usual suspects involved in the making of the film; writer, directors, producers and the actor who played Artie. Hopefully one of them will response in due course.

Comment: For the record, I'm reasonably sure the answer is going to be "died during childbirth".